# CAML Query Help?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0, caml

Is there a way to get all versions of list item(s) using a CAML Query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's exposed directly in any of the APIs that take CAML queries as parameters. You'll probably need to get the current version of the ListItem using your CAML query and then make another call to get all versions of that item.